# How to set a custom color to a HSSCell using POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I would like to set a custom color to a `CellStyle` in POI, but it doesn't seem to be getting applied.

I have the following code:

```
HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("Bank Statement");

HSSFPalette palette = workBook.getCustomPalette();
palette.setColorAtIndex((short) 1, (byte) 60, (byte) 120, (byte) 216);

HSSFColor color = palette.findSimilarColor(60, 120, 216);

CellStyle cellStyleHeader = workBook.createCellStyle();
cellStyleHeader.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cellStyleHeader.setFillForegroundColor(color);
cellStyleHeader.setFont(createHeaderFont(workBook));

HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
cell.setCellValue("Date");
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

No background color is being applied. The color is white. The value of `color` is non null, but is not the same color (when run via a debugger):
[image]

What's the correct way to set a custom color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems [void setFillForegroundColor(Color color)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Color-) does not work properly for `HSSFColor`.

In the binary Excel file format (`*.xls`, `HSSF`) all colors need to be indexed in a color palette. So a custom color needs overwriting a default palette color. And to set the fill foreground color, the index should be used rather than the color itself. So [void setFillForegroundColor(short bg)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-short-) should be used for `HSSF`.

Following code works to set custom fill foreground color for `XSSF` as well as for `HSSF`. For `HSSF` it overwrites the `HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIME` color in palette.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

public class CreateExcelCellFillCustomColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  byte[] rgb = new byte[]{(byte) 60, (byte) 120, (byte) 216};

  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xls";
  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";

  CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgb, null);
   cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = (HSSFWorkbook)workbook;
   HSSFPalette palette = hssfworkbook.getCustomPalette();
   palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIME.getIndex(), rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
   HSSFColor color = palette.findSimilarColor(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
   //cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color); // does not work correctly for HSSF
   cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color.getIndex());   
  }
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
  cell.setCellValue("test");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Axel. That HSSFCellStyle setFillForegroundColor(color)is based on code you supplied in https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66052 - the difference seems to be the code added to POI uses index2 instead of index - should we switch over to index and ignore index2?

Comment: @PJ Fanning: Sorry, cannot help. I gave up trying to contribute to Apache POI. Following the code through the different libraries and classes is a pain because it often lacks documentation. So it is hard to tell what side effects code changes will have. What exactly is the difference between `HSSFColor.getIndex()` and `HSSFColor.getIndex2()`? Seems not documented somewhere.

Comment: I strongly suspect the difference is flowing up from the low-level records. Probably start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/df39e66a-8f99-4f41-beeb-4f5c8a1d2593 and then read the docs for the style related records

Comment: @Gagravarr: You have deeper bothered with this? I doubt that. I have. I found that Apache POI not follows the Microsoft documentation. [2.5.249 StyleXF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/38cad019-5977-49bf-a55a-6e2e9feaca74) -> [icvFore (7 bits)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/6502ad1b-0918-4ee7-9034-10a968f39dad) -> [Icv](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/b7160f4e-abe8-444d-a76c-8f076a007d98). But that is not what Apache POI has programmed.